# Finding the Serial Number of a previously paired device (windows/ios)

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I think someone took my bluetooth headphones.

I live in a student accommodation - and I've tried walking around and picking up the different Bluetooth devices in the flats.

Most devices only show the serial number, and not the name.

I was wondering if it was possible to pull the serial number for windows or IOS (the device has been paired with my laptop and my phone).

Thanks